# django pisa - pagenumber just for two or more pages - show pagenumber of total pages

Tags: django, pisa, page-numbering

Is there a posibility to show the pagenumber with django pisa just for two or more pages?
The template for showing up pagenumber looks like this:

```
<div id="footerContent">
   <p>Page <pdf:pagenumber></p>
</div>
```

I think it's necessary to get the number of pages, before they are processed by pisa. Any option to use an if/else statement like this pseudo:

```
if pages > 1:
 ...
else:
 ...
```

If you want to display e.g. **Page 1/5** (page one of five) it's also necessary to get the count of pages ?! No solution in pisa for that?

Answer (score 2):

I had problem with adding a counter that would tell me what page number i was looking at out of the total amount of pages in the document. It got it to work when i switch the pisa import from:

```
import ho.pisa as pisa
```

to

```
import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
```

Install xhtml2pdf with pip

```
pip install xhtml2pdf
```

This is what my footer looks like now

```
<div id="footerContent">
    {%block page_foot%}
        Page <pdf:pagenumber> / <pdf:pagecount>
    {%endblock%}
</div>
```

Comment: Middasparka, your 1-char edits only purpose is to game SO for reputation?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the current version of python-pisa. There is however some patches for it. If you use the version of pisa or xhtml2pdf from this github you will be able to get total number of pages.

https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf

My template footer looks like this:

```
<div id="footerContent">
  "Page: <pdf:pagenumber> / <pdf:pagecount>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it without using https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf.
What i did is, 
i use page break as below:

```
<h1 style="display:none">PAGECOUNT</h1>
```

and CSS for h1 is

```
h1 {
    page-break-before:always;
}
```

Now, you can get page count using

```
<your-html-string>.count('PAGECOUNT') + 1
```